# use bootstrap show the modal in the angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

The demand is to use ngFor get the list, click on the  tab to show the bootstrap modal, but every modal id is the same in the list,causing the contents of each modal is the first interview, Now the idea is to get to the index, and index will be passed to the id. the question now is how to pass into the index, and this idea is correct?

```
<tr *ngFor="let interview of interviews; let i = index" role="row" class="gradeA">
   <td class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.company.name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.inviter.real_name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id==0">未知</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id!=0">{{ interview.interviewee.real_name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.notice_type==0">
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal">短信</a>
     <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">通知内容</h4>
              </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <span style="font-weight:bold;">公司名称：</span><p>{{ interview.company.name }}</p>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;">面试官：</span><p>{{ interview.inviter.real_name }}</p>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;">应聘者：</span><p>{{ interview.interviewee.real_name }}</p>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;">通知内容：</span><p>{{ interview.notice_content }}</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can approach with this solution, just create 1 dialog popup and pass it selectedInterview object.

```
selectedInterview: any;
showPopup(interviewObj) {
   this.selectedInterview = interviewObj;
}
```

We seperate template into 2 parts, 1 for loop interview and 1 for dialog popup

```
<tr *ngFor="let interview of interviews; let i = index" role="row" class="gradeA">
   <td class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.company.name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;">{{ interview.inviter.real_name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id==0">未知</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.interviewee.user_id!=0">{{ interview.interviewee.real_name }}</td>
   <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="interview.notice_type==0">
   <a data-toggle="modal" (click)="showPopup(interview)" data-target="modal">短信</a>
</td>
```

Note that: **ng-container** check if selectedInterview is undefined to show in popup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">通知内容</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-container *ngIf="selectedInterview !== undefined">
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">公司名称：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.company.name }}</p>
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">面试官：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.inviter.real_name }}</p>
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">应聘者：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.interviewee.real_name }}</p>
          <span style="font-weight:bold;">通知内容：</span><p>{{ selectedInterview.notice_content }}</p>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.but it doesnot work.I think (click)="showPopup(interview)" and data-target="modal" conflict...